How to find when was redis cache last cleared | Magento domain
How to find when was redis cache last cleared | Magento domain
is there way to find the details?
Checked redis info details, is the uptime info is linked with cache clearing. How often redis will clear it cache
Please help with the above query

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
